# Getting a column from a grouped dataframe having certain difference of two largest values of another column in each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

My dataframe `df` is:

```
    Election Year   Votes   Party   Region
  0   2000           50      A       a
  1   2000           100     B       a
  2   2000           70      C       a
  3   2000           26      A       b
  4   2000           180     B       b
  5   2000           100     C       b 
  6   2000           120     A       c
  7   2000           46      B       c
  8   2000           80      C       c
  9   2005           129     A       a
  10  2005           46      B       a
  11  2005           95      C       a
  12  2005           60      A       b
  13  2005           23      B       b
  14  2005           95      C       b
  15  2005           16      A       c
  16  2005           65      B       c
  17  2005           35      C       c
```

I want to get the regions in which the two largest parties have a Vote difference of less than 50 every year. So the desired output is:

```
 Region
  a
  c
```

These are two regions where the top two parties had a Vote difference of <50 every year.

I tried to groupby using "Election Year" and "Region" and then sort the Votes in descending order. But I am unable to check if the difference between top two votes of each region in every year is less than 50.

how can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your idea with sorting (`sort_values`) + grouping (`GroupBy`), then getting the difference `diff()`, which gives you the the number of votes difference:

```
>>> df = df.sort_values(['Votes'])
>>> votes_diff = df.groupby(['Election Year', 'Region'])['Votes'].diff()
```

We can join with the original dataframe and re-sort on the index to see what happened with respect to the original data:

```
>>> df.join(votes_diff.rename('Δ votes')).sort_index()
    Election Year  Votes Party Region  Δ votes
0            2000     50     A      a      NaN
1            2000    100     B      a     30.0
2            2000     70     C      a     20.0
3            2000     26     A      b      NaN
4            2000    180     B      b     80.0
5            2000    100     C      b     74.0
6            2000    120     A      c     40.0
7            2000     46     B      c      NaN
8            2000     80     C      c     34.0
9            2005    129     A      a     34.0
10           2005     46     B      a      NaN
11           2005     95     C      a     49.0
12           2005     60     A      b     37.0
13           2005     23     B      b      NaN
14           2005     95     C      b     35.0
15           2005     16     A      c      NaN
16           2005     65     B      c     30.0
17           2005     35     C      c     19.0
```

So in each election, each party now has a value `Δ votes` which is how many more votes it has than the next party. The smallest party of each election as `NaN` as its vote counts.

Now we want in each election the difference between the 2 largest parties, meaning the `Δ votes` for the row with the maximum of votes. We could probably use `idxmax`, but since the dataframe is already sorted on vote counts, we can also just use `last`.

```
>>> top_vote_diff = votes_diff.groupby([df['Election Year'], df['Region']]).last()
>>> top_vote_diff
Election Year  Region
2000           a         30.0
               b         80.0
               c         40.0
2005           a         34.0
               b         35.0
               c         30.0
Name: Votes, dtype: float64
```

Now check it’s less than 50 `lt(50)` for all elections in that region:

```
>>> criteria = top_vote_diff.lt(50).groupby('Region').all()
>>> criteria
Region
a     True
b    False
c     True
Name: Votes, dtype: bool
>>> pd.Series(criteria.index[criteria])
0   a
1   c
Name: Region, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. How to find the regions in which minimum two parties got more than 50 votes?

Comment: @Dpk That’s a pretty different issue. I think a boolean series (on parties having > 50 votes) on which you can do `.groupby(...).sum() >= 2`

Comment: in your first answer, how to get the list of only those Regions with True boolean value?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `.pivot`:

```py
df = df.pivot(
    index=["Region", "Election Year"], columns="Party", values="Votes"
)
df["diff"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).head(2).diff()[-1] * -1, axis=1
)
x = df.groupby(level=0)["diff"].apply(lambda x: (x < 50).all())
print(pd.DataFrame(x.index[x]))
```

Prints:

```
  Region
0      a
1      c
```

---

Steps:

```py
df = df.pivot(
    index=["Region", "Election Year"], columns="Party", values="Votes"
)
```

Creates:

```
Party                   A    B    C
Region Election Year               
a      2000            50  100   70
       2005           129   46   95
b      2000            26  180  100
       2005            60   23   95
c      2000           120   46   80
       2005            16   65   35
```

```py
df["diff"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).head(2).diff()[-1] * -1, axis=1
)
```

Creates:

```
Party                   A    B    C  diff
Region Election Year                     
a      2000            50  100   70  30.0
       2005           129   46   95  34.0
b      2000            26  180  100  80.0
       2005            60   23   95  35.0
c      2000           120   46   80  40.0
       2005            16   65   35  30.0
```

```py
x = df.groupby(level=0)["diff"].apply(lambda x: (x < 50).all())
```

Creates:

```
Region
a     True
b    False
c     True
```